# 3D Heat Equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, simulation, temperature, pde

I am trying to model in MATLAB the temperature distribution inside a rectangular prism with [boundary and initial conditions and heat equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJmd.png) I was trying to visualize 2D slices in the 3D shape. However, the simulation takes too long and when I try to change the time step, I get stability issues and the output visuals look weird and inconsistent. Is there a way to fix this? The code I used is below:

```
clear; clf;

rho = 1;
cp = 1;
k = 1;

alpha = rho / (cp * k);

Lx = 10;
Ly = 10;
Lz = 10;

Nx = 21; Nt = 35*60;
Ny = 21;
Nz = 21;
dx = Lx / (Nx - 1);
dy = Ly / (Ny - 1);
dz = Lz / (Nz - 1);

c = 1;
C = 0.1;
dt = C * dx / c;

Tn = zeros(Nx, Ny, Nz);
x = linspace(0, Lx, Nx);
y = linspace(0, Ly, Ny);
z = linspace(0, Lz, Nz);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);

Tn(:, :, :) = 80;
t = 0;

Tn(1, :, :) = 350; Tn(end, :, :) = 350;
Tn(:, 1, :) = 350; Tn(:, end, :) = 350;
Tn(:, :, 1) = 350; Tn(:, :, end) = 350;

figure;
title(sprintf('Time = %f seconds', t));

for n = 1:Nt
    Tc = Tn;

    t = t + dt;
    for i = 2:Nx - 1
        for j = 2:Ny - 1
            for k = 2:Nz - 1
                Tn(i,j,k)=Tc(i,j,k) +...
                    dt * alpha *...
                    (((Tc(i+1,j,k) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i-1,j,k))/dx/dx)+...
                    ((Tc(i,j+1,k) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i,j-1,k))/dy/dy)+...
                    ((Tc(i,j,k+1) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i,j,k-1))/dz/dz));
            end
        end
    end

    % Display slices in the XZ plane
    slice(X, Y, Z, Tn, [], Lx/2, []);

    xlabel('X (inches)');
    ylabel('Y (inches)');
    zlabel('Z (inches)');
    title(sprintf('Time = %f seconds', t));

    % Pause for a short duration to visualize the changes
    pause(0.1);
end
```

I was trying to get an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXsiF.png). However, the simulation takes too long and after a short time there does not seem to be any temperature change whatsoever. When I increase the time step, I get a [weird result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7XS9.png). Do I have to wait for the simulation to take its time? And are there inconsistencies or flaws in my implementation of the heat equation in MATLAB?

Comment: Try first optimizing your code. for a 3D matrix `Tc`, `Tn(i,j,k)=Tc(i+1,j,k)-2*Tc(i,j,k)` is the same as (without loops) `Tn(1:end-1,:,:)=Tc(2:end,:,:)-2*Tc(1:end-1,:,:)`, for example. You can essentially remove the i,j,k loops to speed up your code significantly.

Comment: Also Nt*0.1=3.5 minutes. The `pause` is that long.

Answer (score 1):

Several things with your code:

1- vectorize forms of the operation will speed up the code significantly. (see below)

2- you `pause(0.1)` to visualize. `Nt*0.1=210`, i.e. your code spends 3.5 minutes paused, therefore is slow. use `drawnow`.

3- Your `dt` is too big. If you run it with `c=1` you will see it indeed goes weird. This is due to numerical inaccuracies, your simulation breaks. Reduce dt (e.g. `c=5`) and you will see this does not happen.

[image]

Code:

```
rho = 1;
cp = 1;
k = 1;

alpha = rho / (cp * k);

Lx = 10;
Ly = 10;
Lz = 10;

Nx = 21; Nt = 35*60;
Ny = 21;
Nz = 21;

dx = Lx / (Nx - 1);
dy = Ly / (Ny - 1);
dz = Lz / (Nz - 1);

c = 5;
C = 0.1;
dt = C * dx / c;

Tn = zeros(Nx, Ny, Nz);
x = linspace(0, Lx, Nx);
y = linspace(0, Ly, Ny);
z = linspace(0, Lz, Nz);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);

Tn(:, :, :) = 80;
t = 0;

Tn(1, :, :) = 350; Tn(end, :, :) = 350;
Tn(:, 1, :) = 350; Tn(:, end, :) = 350;
Tn(:, :, 1) = 350; Tn(:, :, end) = 350;

figure;
title(sprintf('Time = %f seconds', t));

for n = 1:Nt
    Tc = Tn;

    t = t + dt;

    Tn=Tc;
    Tn(2:end-1,:,:)=Tn(2:end-1,:,:)+dt*alpha/dx^2*(Tc(3:end,:,:)-2*Tc(2:end-1,:,:)+Tc(1:end-2,:,:));
    Tn(:,2:end-1,:)=Tn(:,2:end-1,:)+dt*alpha/dy^2*(Tc(:,3:end,:)-2*Tc(:,2:end-1,:)+Tc(:,1:end-2,:));
    Tn(:,:,2:end-1)=Tn(:,:,2:end-1)+dt*alpha/dz^2*(Tc(:,:,3:end)-2*Tc(:,:,2:end-1)+Tc(:,:,1:end-2));

%     for i = 2:Nx - 1
%         for j = 2:Ny - 1
%             for k = 2:Nz - 1
%                 Tn(i,j,k)=Tc(i,j,k) +...
%                     dt * alpha *...
%                     (((Tc(i+1,j,k) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i-1,j,k))/dx/dx)+...
%                     ((Tc(i,j+1,k) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i,j-1,k))/dy/dy)+...
%                     ((Tc(i,j,k+1) - 2*Tc(i,j,k) + Tc(i,j,k-1))/dz/dz));
%             end
%         end
%     end

    % Display slices in the XZ plane
    h=slice(X, Y, Z, Tn, [], Lx/2, []);
    set(h,'edgecolor','none')    
    xlabel('X (inches)');
    ylabel('Y (inches)');
    zlabel('Z (inches)');
    title(sprintf('Time = %f seconds', t));

    % Pause for a short duration to visualize the changes
    drawnow
end
```